# Tetrahedron Permutations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, permutations

> There are 2 identical regular tetrahedrons. Each is painted with 1 red face, 1 blue face, 1 green face, and 1 yellow face.
>   Will they always be painted in the same way?
>   Clarification: They are painted in the same way if you cannot tell them apart from each other.

This is the type of problem I can easily get through common sense / visualization but then feel I am cheating myself by not using any math. Is there a way to frame this as a permutation, perhaps by "unfolding" / flattening the tetrahedron and then viewing it as a rotation?

I visualize it as a circular permutation of three items (three triangles) around an unchanging central item (since the rotation or reflection does not affect the central item). This would lead to (3-1)! Permuatations around the center / circle, i.e. 2 distinct arrangements. Technically any of them can be the center triangle depending on how we choose to flatten / unfold it.

This is easy to conceptualize and visualize, but I'm not satisfied. The main reason is that in 2 dimensions it's possible to make 8 combinations (I think), because each of the 4 colors could be at the center, and each central color can have 2 distinct permutations in a circle around it. How can I mathematically account for the introduction of the 3rd dimension? Clearly eliminating one of the variables works but I'm not sure why yet...
Can someone help?

NOTE: I found this problem in the "Brilliant" app and got the correct answer, but feel there's something more to be learned here than I have taken from it.

Comment: You're right in stating that you can 'eliminate a variable', when visualising in 3 dimensions, there is no 'centre piece', as any side of a regular tetrahedron can be taken as a base. Further explanation will come from Topology I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use math?  The symmetry group of a regular tetrahedron is isomorphic to $A_4.$

The ways to apply 4 paint colors to an asymmetric tetrahedron is isomorphic to $S_4$

$A_4$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$

There are 2 cosets.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to investigate this answer or my own in further detail to fully understand it, but now I know where to look to get the concept. Cheers!

Comment: Is there a good article or book that you would recommend for further reading?

Comment: This response is a little bit of a sledgehammer to crack a walnut.  You can find this in any book on abstract algebra.  Read the sections on groups and symmetric groups.  It is not particularly easy stuff to get your head around at first though.  There are also some videos on youtube that will provide some introductions to group theory.

Comment: Thank you, I'll certainly look into that as an introduction and begin working my way into it. Cheers 

Answer (score 1):

If you place a tetrahedron on a surface so it has one of the sides at the bottom, then you can turn it to see one of the three other faces. Let's call such a turn a *rotation*.  And let's call it a *flip* when you place a different side at the bottom. So: a single tetrahedron allows for 3 rotations and 4 flips, resulting in 12 different 2D representations. Since there are 24 different colorings of the 2D representation, you indeed get 2 different paintings.

Now, the effect that a rotation has on a 2D representation is obvious: just rotate the colors on the outside. Indeed, this is why you didn't even consider all 24 different colorings, and just considered the 8 different ones that are invariant under rotation.

On the other hand, the effect of a flip on a 2D representation is far less obvious. Indeed, given two 2D representations with a different color in the middle, can you quickly tell if they represent the same tetrahedron or not? Still, while you may have a hard time figuring out which are the same and which are different, you know for a fact that the same one tetrahedron can be represented with each one of the 4 sides in the middle. This is why the 8 needs to be divided by 4 to give 2 possible paintings, as you visually figured out as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good explanation. I thought it might be more complex but that is sensible.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I just kept one color around the circle in the same spot since that would account for only the unique permutations.

Comment: @Hanzy Of course, I understand.   I was trying to illustrate how what you did with the rotations also applies to the color in the 'middle' ... it's the same kind of thinking that shows a connection between a 3D operation (whether it's turning it around to get a different color at the bottom, or whether it is a rotation) and how that relates to a 2D representation.

Comment: That's a very good explanation (just read the updated one). I had thought of unfolding it but thinking of putting it on a flat surface and covering one side really makes it even more relatable. 

Comment: @Hanzy Thanks.  I am always much more into conceptual explanations rather than purely quantitative ones :)